# Jquery Modal/Dialog with Fullscreen option

Tags: jquery, plugins, modal-dialog, fullscreen

I am looking to use a Jquery modal/dialog plugin for my site to view content.

I am currently using Thickbox which works well but it does not have a fullscreen option, when I say fullscreen I mean fill the whole browser window.

Does anyone know of any good modal/dialog plugins which can expand fullscreen?

Cheers

Eef

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thickbox should support what you're attempting to do out of the box.  See this [forum thread](http://www.webmasterworld.com/javascript/3864595.htm), wherein they discuss initializing the TB's size:

```
TB_height = $(window).height();
```

And alternatively specifying a `resize` event handler to `window` to update a TB that is already being displayed.

If you're looking for an alternative plugin, I'd suggest looking into [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#options), as the CSS for its overlay is easily configurable, and you should be able to accomplish a full-size dialog by using `100%` for the `height` and `width` properties.

Answer (score 1):

http://mabp.kiev.ua/2010/12/15/jquery-ui-fullscreen-button-for-dialog/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of window.height, you should use screen properties for full screen.

```
TB_height = screen.height;
TB_width = screen.width;
```

Answer (score 0):

this plugin [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) that has a simple code. You can search in the event window resize and scroll. there should amend the height and width options to fill the window. 
It has a bug that is fixed in this way, you can modify these lines in FancyBox:

line 432

```
$(window).unbind("resize scroll", $.fn.fancybox.scrollBox);
```

line 439

```
$(window).unbind("resize scroll", $.fn.fancybox.scrollBox);
```